# Linking Models in Backbone-relational

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

How would you go about linking models using backbone-relational.js to then allow views specific to the id that the relations are keyed on?

As an example, model **tickets** hasMany model **ticketAssignments**, and model **ticketAssignments** hasOne model **user**. The flow of the app would be to see the full list of **ticket(s)**, and then click into a ticket to see the list of **user(s)** assigned.

I have tried following the main backbone-relational example, but can't seem to get it working (let me know if example code would be helpful).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you're having is a many-to-many relationship with a linking model `ticketAssignment`. You could check out [Backbone-JJRelational](https://github.com/jj-studio/Backbone-JJRelational) which provides many-to-many relationships without a linking model. Set up your models as described in the docs and then use something like this to get the users name:

```
ticket.get('users').each(function (user) {
    console.log(user.get('name'));
});
```